# Enabling Chromium to sync with Google Account

Tags: chromium

Google [announced](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/01/limiting-private-api-availability-in.html) that from March 15 2021 for the open-source version of Google Chrome, Chromium, it is limiting Private API availability.

The main implication of this change is that is no longer possible to sync Chromium bookmarks, tabs, etc. with a Google Account.

On i.a. Arch Linux, Chromium can be installed from the repositories, whereas Chrome can only be installed from the Arch User Repository (a more roundabout way).

Is there a way to re-enable the syncing of a Google Account in Chromium?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Launching Chromium with flags setting a oauth2 ID and secret can re-enable the syncing of Chromium with a Google Account.

The `oauth2-client-id` should be set to: `77185425430.apps.googleusercontent.com`
The corresponding `oauth2-secret` should be set to: `OTJgUOQcT7lO7GsGZq2G4IlT`

E.g. on Arch Linux this can be done by creating the file `~/.config/chromium-flags.conf` with the contents:

```
--oauth2-client-id=77185425430.apps.googleusercontent.com
--oauth2-client-secret=OTJgUOQcT7lO7GsGZq2G4IlT
```

It should be noted that Google recommends against doing this. It is also not clear for how long this workaround will work.

**Edit**: I recently came in posession of a system on which I only managed to install Ubuntu. On Ubuntu it worked by passing the flags directly in the command. That should work on any OS.

**Still working as of March 2024 (Chromium 123)**

Comment: after doing that, the browser is restarted?

Comment: Yes, restart it completely, reboot might be easiest way to do it

Comment: Using this `~/.config/chromium-flags.conf` doesn't seem to allow me to re-sync with my Google account. I guess this workaround has stopped working?! (I'm using v92.0.4515.131.)

Comment: @sjakobi for me it still works. Chromium 92 (on 2 devices). Did you restart?

Comment: Have anyone tried this on Windows 10?

Comment: It looks like this id and secret come from sourcecode : https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/b08bf82b0df37d15a822b478e23ce633616ed959/google_apis/google_api_keys.cc

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work (anymore) with version 98.0.4758.9 on Ubuntu 20.04, KDE neon 5.24.

Comment: Does this still work for anyone else?

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: A warning to anyone who does this, Google doesn't seem to understand what the term **sync** means. I expected newer data to overwrite older stuff stored in my account... but nope. Passwords that I had updated since sync was disabled were not overwritten. Not sure what else was broken because that was an immediate deal-breaker. Good thing I made a backup of `~/.config/chromium/` first.

Comment: It worked for me only once I also created an apikeys file in /etc/chromium.d including the API keys assigned by Google to Debian (for Raspberry Pi 4 model B), see here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=334758&hilit=chrome+sync

Comment: I just happen to have done this yesterday for the first time in Ubuntu, just passing the flags in the command

Comment: Great answer thanks! - works on Manjaro.

Comment: I was able to get it work as Bastiaan Quast suggested to pass on command line on debian.   did not work with putting in file.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with the Fedora version of Chromium. The sync option just isn't there.

Answer (score 8):

This solution works for me on Windows 10/11 latest Chromium ver. 111.0.5534.0. I was able to sync my account and use all Google services (sync, safebrowsing, voice search, etc):

https://gist.github.com/cvan/44a6d60457b20133191bd7b104f9dcc4

---

1. Download [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium).
2. You'll notice a yellow disclaimer message appear as a doorhanger: `Google API Keys are missing. Some functionality of Chromium will be disabled. Learn More.`
3. Clicking on that link takes you to the confusing [API Keys docs page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys).
4. If you aren't already, subscribe to the [chromium-dev@chromium.org mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/chromium-dev). (You can just subscribe to the list and choose to not receive any mail. FYI: the Chromium project restricts the APIs to those subscribed to that group - that is, Chromium devs.)
5. Make sure you are logged in with the Google account associated with the email address that you used to subscribe to chromium-dev.
6. Log in to the [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/), and [select an existing project](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects) or press the "Create Project" button.
7. From the project's [API Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library), select the [Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) tab in the sidebar.
8. Create a [Browser API Key](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/key?type=CLIENT_SIDE).
9. You'll see a modal with an API key. Copy and paste that somewhere.
10. Now create an [OAuth Client ID](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient).
11. After you complete all the steps and the "content screen," you'll be presented with a modal with your Google Client ID and Client Secret.
12. You'll need to set three environment variables:

**On Windows:** Launch `cmd.exe` and enter the following commands:

```
setx GOOGLE_API_KEY your_key_goes_here
setx GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID your_client_id_goes_here
setx GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET your_client_secret_goes_here
```

**On Mac OS X / Linux:** Plop these in your `~/.profile` file:

```
export GOOGLE_API_KEY="your_key_goes_here"
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID="your_client_id_goes_here"
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET="your_client_secret_goes_here"
```

13. Now launch Chromium:

**On Windows:** Launch Chromium normally.

**On Mac OS X:**

```
/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium
```

Comment: There appear "Turn on sync ..." button after I enabled api key and client id  and secret variables. But when trying to click it I see log following message: 56543:56543:1207/215109.516005:ERROR:turn_sync_on_helper.cc(248)] Cannot turn Sync On for invalid account.
but in google console there is also message: Note: It may take 5 minutes to a few hours for settings to take effect 
so it may take some time before the id is propagated...I will try tomorrow

Comment: Try https://www.learningtopi.com/sbc/chromium-sync/ if it doesn't work tomorrow.

Comment: So, it just took some time after enablement, it took few hours before the API key and credentials started working. Now it works, thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for syncing Chromium with Google, and I did find another process in the past, but having problems finding it again, as I didn't bookmark it or can't find it in my bookmarks. It involves logging into google, via browser, and adding Chromium in some list to allow it to sync. I guess it is like when you add apps to your account from websites. The problem is, I don't remember where to go to do this and what steps were involved.

Anyway, I just added(Aug-2021) these switches listed on this page to the latest portable chromium 61.0.3153.0 (Official Build) (64-bit), and it worked, which was a lot easier then having to log into Google and add chromium as some kind of permitted app.

Comment: Thanks, in future, I would add this as a comment to my answer above, instead of an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has installed Chromium using Flatpak (e.g., Fedora users), I'm writing this solution. I applied the id and secret via environment variables using the following command:

```
flatpak override --user --env=GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID=<oauth2-client-id> --env=GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET=<oauth2-client-secret> org.chromium.Chromium
```

By combining the above with the excellent solutions from other comments, I was able to resolve the issue.