# How to change default macos app launching?

Tags: macos, chromium, launching

In the [question about Chromium-ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67459316/enabling-chromium-to-sync-with-google-account) sync was answer about lunching app via terminal like
"/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium"
and this launching work wish sync when launching via simple click to Chromium.app don't work.

What the reason of different application behavior? And how I can set to the app to launching like command "/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium" when I just click to Chromium.app in macbook?

upd
I tried to create additional app via applescript and if I run script

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "/Applications/Chromium-Gost.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium-Gost"
end tell
```

it run successful, but if i run script without Terminal it launch without sync

```
do shell script "/Applications/Chromium-Gost.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium-Gost"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not run an application like this, I mean by referring directly its executable path.

Use `launch` (AppleScript) command with the application name or use Terminal `open -a Chromium-Ghost`. Both are commands to run an application as if clicking on its icon.

Clicking on an application icon does some over things than simply running the executable.